# how to match the value of two variables in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was just wondering how I can match the value of two variable, for example if I have

```
 var A = [1,2,3];
 var b = [A,B,C];
```

how can I output the first value of each and second value of each and so on, so the output will become

```
 A1,B2,C3
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [jQuery.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map):

```
var a = ['A','B','C'];
var b = [1,2,3];

var result = $.map(a, function(n, i){
  return n + b[i];
}); // ["A1", "B2", "C3"]
```

Comment: thanks, the (a) in the $.map(a), is that the name of the first variable or is it sth different.
thanks

Comment: sorry to bother you again, is it possible to add spaces between A1 letters too, to make it look like A  1,B  2 or A * 1, B * 2
thanks

Comment: @amir, just change the return to `return n + ' ' + b[i];`